# How would i go about making a settings file out of a text document?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a small game project with pygame before moving onto a larger project.

Part of this is making a settings file with a text document, so far I'm splitting the text file up but I still need to move it into the pygame screen code (this is for changing the resolution)

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
settings = open("settings.txt","r")
Bsettings = settings.read().split(",")
print (Bsettings)
Display = pygame.display.set_mode((Bsettings))
pygame.display.set_caption("BT")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem completely. But for configuration purpose, [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) files are often used. And there are libraries out there (JSON one is in the standard library) to parse those files.

YAML and JSON are text files with particular formats.

If you wanted to display some text in your game, which is stored in a configuration file, you could do something like this:

Make a configuration file 'config.json' (I'll use a JSON file in this example)

```
{
    "stage_one_text": "Welcome to Stage one",
    "boss_line": "I kick ass"
}
```

Load the configuration file from your program, and make use of it

```
import json

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    CONFIG = json.load(config_file)

print(CONFIG['boss_line'])
```

Comment: I did this and it seems to work but i'm having this issue on the pygame end of things:

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((CONFIG['screen_resolution']))

TypeError: must be sequence of length 2, not 7

From a JSON file that has this:

{

"screen_resolution": "800,600"

}

Comment: @CharlieK `len("800,600")` is 7. Did you mean to use `"screen_resolution": [800,600]`?

Comment: That fixed it - thanks, didn't realise you could use square brackets rather than " " or ' '